# Notify users who starred a question on updates

Tags: feature-request, notifications, bookmarks

Many times I find many question interesting and I would like to follow them as the answers comes and goes.

When I just startes SO I used to save the tabs and refresh the pages now and then.

Then I discovered that I could mark a question favorite and come back to them by browsing my history. But I often forget a about the questions after a while.

**Feature request:**

*Option 1:*

When marking a question as favorite you'll receive updates/notifications on answers and progress along the posts lifetime in your Recent Inbox messages.

*Option 2:*

Another approach is to make another button as a **Follow Question Button**.

Sometimes questions aren't particularly good, but the answers coming are worth more than gold. This can make users receive updates/notifications on answers and progress along the posts lifetime in your Recent Inbox messages, but not give the OP undeservedly points.

I bet someone have thought about this before... is there a reason this functionality doesn't exist?

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would love to see Option 1 implemented. There is a downside though too. Some users only star questions that they want to revisit later, and notifying them of every change is not what they want.

Bloating the UI adding another button similar to starring (Option 2), doesn't seem an option either, but it might be the only option.

Another option I could think of is setting a property in the user profile to receive notifications on starred questions. The downside of this option is that you can't pick for which questions you do want notifications and which not.

For me, still Option 1 would be preferred.

Comment: I also believe option 1 is the most clean solution. Though badly asked questions might get many undeserved favorite points because sometimes users would want to follow the answers not the question.

Comment: You don't really gain points by having your question marked as favorite, so no harm done. And that badge, nobody actually cares about them.

Comment: Oh..I see. Then I hope SO will consider such a solution as option 1.